# Airflow - How to pass xcom variable into Python function

Tags: airflow

I need to reference a variable that's returned by a `BashOperator`. In my `task_archive_s3_file`, I need to get the filename from `get_s3_file`. The task simply prints `{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids=submit_file_to_spark) }}` as a string instead of the value.

If I use the `bash_command`, the value prints correctly.

```py
get_s3_file = PythonOperator(
    task_id='get_s3_file',
    python_callable=obj.func_get_s3_file,
    trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_SUCCESS,
    dag=dag)

submit_file_to_spark = BashOperator(
    task_id='submit_file_to_spark',
    bash_command="echo 'hello world'",
    trigger_rule="all_done",
    xcom_push=True,
    dag=dag)

task_archive_s3_file = PythonOperator(
    task_id='archive_s3_file',
#    bash_command="echo {{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='submit_file_to_spark') }}",
    python_callable=obj.func_archive_s3_file,
    params={'s3_path_filename': "{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids=submit_file_to_spark) }}" },
    dag=dag)

get_s3_file >> submit_file_to_spark >> task_archive_s3_file
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Templates like `{{ ti.xcom_pull(...) }}` can only be used inside of parameters that support templates or they won't be rendered prior to execution. See the `template_fields`, `template_fields_renderers` and `template_ext` attributes of the [PythonOperator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/operators/python.py#L124-L125) and [BashOperator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/operators/bash.py#L125-L130).

So `templates_dict` is what you use to pass templates to your python operator:

```py
def func_archive_s3_file(**context):
    archive(context['templates_dict']['s3_path_filename'])

task_archive_s3_file = PythonOperator(
    task_id='archive_s3_file',
    dag=dag,
    python_callable=obj.func_archive_s3_file,
    provide_context=True,  # must pass this because templates_dict gets passed via context
    templates_dict={'s3_path_filename': "{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='submit_file_to_spark') }}" })
```

However in the case of fetching an XCom value, another alternative is just using the `TaskInstance` object made available to you via context:

```py
def func_archive_s3_file(**context):
    archive(context['ti'].xcom_pull(task_ids='submit_file_to_spark'))

task_archive_s3_file = PythonOperator(
    task_id='archive_s3_file',
    dag=dag,
    python_callable=obj.func_archive_s3_file,
    provide_context=True,
```

Comment: Dumb question but if I use the last example via the `xcom_pull`, would it re-run said task? I was under the assumpton that xcoms get passed from task to task (in order). In my example, I need the filename that is given from the very first task.

Comment: Nope it would not re-run the task. XCom push/pull just adds/retrieves a row from the xcom table in the airflow DB based on DAG id, execution date, task id, and key. Declaring the dependency of `submit_file_to_spark >> task_archive_s3_file` like you already have should be sufficient to ensure that the filename is pushed into xcom before it is retrieved.

Comment: Too bad you can only pass strings this way. I want to pass objects.

Comment: @Julio you technically can send pickled objects via XCom, but it will be deprecated in Airflow 2.0 due to security concerns, see related `enable_xcom_pickling` config for more details.

Comment: @tatlar can u please have a look at similar issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631581/airflow-2-0-2-how-to-pass-parameter-within-postgres-tasks-using-xcom

Answer (score 80):

Upvoted both the question and the answer, but I think that this can be made a little more clear for those users who just want to pass small data objects between `PythonOperator` tasks in their DAGs. Referencing this question and [this XCom example](https://github.com/trbs/airflow-examples/blob/master/dags/example_xcom.py) got me to the following solution. Super simple:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

DAG = DAG(
  dag_id='example_dag',
  start_date=datetime.now(),
  schedule_interval='@once'
)

def push_function(**kwargs):
    ls = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    return ls

push_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='push_task', 
    python_callable=push_function,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=DAG)

def pull_function(**kwargs):
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    ls = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='push_task')
    print(ls)

pull_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='pull_task', 
    python_callable=pull_function,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=DAG)

push_task >> pull_task
```

I'm not sure why this works, but it does. A few questions for the community:

- What's happening with `ti` here? How is that built in to `**kwargs`?
- Is `provide_context=True` necessary for both functions?

Any edits to make this answer clearer are very welcome!

Comment: This works because any task that returns a value is stored in xcom ([source](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/1.8.2/airflow/models.py#L1392-L1394)). So any return value of `PythonOperator` is saved to XCom (something to be careful with!).  Provide context is required to use the referenced `**kwargs`, which I usually name that as `**context`. This context is the same context you get in jinja templates ([source](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/1.8.2/airflow/models.py#L1550-L1581)). Context provides a lot of useful information specific to a DAG run.

Comment: @DanielHuang One more question: is `provide_context` necessary for both the push and pull, or only for the push?

Comment: Both! To push or pull, you need access to the `TaskInstance` object of the current run, which is only available through `context`.

Comment: Do you have example where `ls = ['a', 'b', 'c']` is not hard-coded like it is coming from params/conf?

Comment: "ti"  is the task instance object. As returned by the first task

Comment: @aaron can u please have a look at similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631581/airflow-2-0-2-how-to-pass-parameter-within-postgres-tasks-using-xcom

Comment: BTW in sub_dag have to be added dag_id='master_id" to xcom_pull

Comment: Hi. When one calls ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='push_task'), is this the instance of the task recieving the information or the task that output that information? Sorry it is to lame of a question

Comment: Hi @Mangostino, when you invoke xcom_pull this is an instance of the task pulling meta data from from the DAG context layer. We in push_task we’re populating the DAG context with information from push_task internal al state and then pulling those into the internal state of pull_task.

Answer (score 19):

Used the same code and modified params like `Startdate` etc.

```
import airflow
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

args = {
    'owner': 'Airflow',
    'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(2),
}

DAG = DAG(
  dag_id='simple_xcom',
  default_args=args,
#  start_date=datetime(2019, 04, 21),
  schedule_interval="@daily",
  #schedule_interval=timedelta(1)
)

def push_function(**context):
    msg='the_message'
    print("message to push: '%s'" % msg)
    task_instance = context['task_instance']
    task_instance.xcom_push(key="the_message", value=msg)

push_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='push_task', 
    python_callable=push_function,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=DAG)

def pull_function(**kwargs):
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    msg = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='push_task',key='the_message')
    print("received message: '%s'" % msg)

pull_task = PythonOperator(`enter code here`
    task_id='pull_task', 
    python_callable=pull_function,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=DAG)

push_task >> pull_task
```

If you wonder where does the `context['task_instance']` and `kwargs['ti']` comes from, you can refer to the [Airflow macro documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/macros.html?highlight=macros)

Comment: where do those names `ti` and 'task_instance' come from?

Comment: @LiuWeibo See Airflow macros: https://airflow.apache.org/code.html#macros

Comment: Airflow Macro link updated: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/macros-ref.html

Comment: @Kiwy can u please have a look at similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631581/airflow-2-0-2-how-to-pass-parameter-within-postgres-tasks-using-xcom

Comment: ti and task_instance are both the same

Answer (score 5):

In Airflow 2.0 (released December 2020), the [TaskFlow API](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial_taskflow_api.html) has made passing XComs easier. With this API, you can simply return values from functions annotated with @task, and they will be passed as XComs behind the scenes. Example from the tutorial:

```
    @task()
    def extract():
        ...
        return order_data_dict
    
    @task()
    def transform(order_data_dict: dict):
        ...
        return total_order_value

    order_data = extract()
    order_summary = transform(order_data)
```

In this example, `order_data` has type `XComArg`. It stores the dictionary returned by the `extract` task. When the `transform` task runs, `order_data` is unwrapped, and the task receives the plain Python object that was stored.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to pass an xcom to a bash operator in airflow 2 use `env`; let's say you have pushed to a xcom `my_xcom_var`, then you can use jinja inside `env` to pull the xcom value, e.g.

```
BashOperator(
    task_id=mytask,
    bash_command="echo ${MYVAR}",
    env={"MYVAR": '{{ ti.xcom_pull(key=\'my_xcom_var\') }}'},
    dag=dag
)
```

Check https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/operators/bash/index.html#module-airflow.operators.bash for more details

Answer (score 1):

The Airflow BaseOperator defines a property `output` that you can use to access the `xcom` content of the given operator. Here is a concrete example

```py
with DAG(...):
    push_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id='push_task', 
        python_callable=lambda: 'Hello, World!')

    pull_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id='pull_task', 
        python_callable=lambda x: print(x),
        op_args=[push_task.output])
```

which should be almost equivalent to

```py
with DAG(...):
    push_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id='push_task', 
        python_callable=lambda: 'Hello, World!')

    pull_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id='pull_task', 
        python_callable=lambda x: print(x),
        op_args=["{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('push_task') }}"])
```

As far as I know, the only difference is that the former implicitly defines `push_task >> pull_task`.