# How to access response of one SImpleHttpOperator and use that response data value to pass as params for the next SimpleHttpOperator task?

Tags: airflow

So assume I have 2 SimpleHttpOperator tasks in my DAG. I need to get a response from the 1st task and use that response data to create params for the second task. Both are GET APIs.

How to get response data from simpleHttpOperator, I tried XCOM as true, but how to get data from XCOM into the second operator?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the code for the [SimpleHttpOperator on Github](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/providers/http/operators/http.py#L53), you can see that the fields '*endpoint*', '*data*' and '*headers*' are **template_fields**, so you can use Jinja templating.

There is an example of how to use xcoms in templating [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html?highlight=xcom#xcoms) and a description of Jinja templating [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html?highlight=xcom#jinja-templating)

I think this question has already been answered in
[Airflow - How to pass xcom variable into Python function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46059161/airflow-how-to-pass-xcom-variable-into-python-function)