Airflow - How to get XCOM from dynamic task
I am creating dynamic tasks in airflow, and I need to access the xcom from those dynamic tasks.
The tasks are generated dynamically, depending on the "topic", see code below.
for topic in ["topic1", "topic2"]:

    deduplicate_insert_master_job = DLISparkCreateBatchJobOperator(
        task_id="deduplicate_insert_master_job_{}".format(topic),
        ...
    )


    deduplicate_insert_master_sensor = DLISparkShowBatchStateSensor(
        task_id="deduplicate_insert_master_sensor_{}".format(topic),
        job_id="{{ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='deduplicate_insert_master_job_{}')['id']}}".format(topic),
    )

In deduplicate_insert_master_sensor task, I need to access to the name, with topic of deduplicate_insert_master_job .
How can I do?
【Have tried so far】

Airflow - How to pass xcom variable into Python function
Apache airflow xcom for variable task id

Thanks!
【Possible Answer】
Airflow Python Operator - Get values from xcom pull for params
"{{{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='push_result_{}') }}}}".format(table_name)
"{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='push_result_%s') }}" % "TABLENAME"

In my specific case, this works:
    deduplicate_insert_master_sensor = DLISparkShowBatchStateSensor(
        task_id="deduplicate_insert_master_sensor_{}".format(topic),
        job_id = "{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='deduplicate_insert_master_job_%s')['id'] }}" % topic
    )


I have found something usefull here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64512308/airflow-python-operator-get-values-from-xcom-pull-for-params. "{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='push_result_%s') }}" % "TABLENAME"
