# Create SSH connection to AWS ec2 instance in Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I have a regular ETL job that runs on an AWS ec2 instance.

The workflow looks like the following:

1. Bring up the ec2 instance using `EC2StartInstanceOperator` operator.
2. Find out public IP using `boto3` function wrapped inside a `PythonOperator`. This operator pushes the IP to XCOM.
3. Establish an SSH hook using the public IP and run a remote command using `SSHOperator`.
4. Stop the ec2 instance upon completion using `EC2StopInstanceOperator`.

The issues with the above are:

1. The SSH hook (`airflow.providers.ssh.hooks.ssh.SSHHook` in Airflow 2.0) can not access XCOM, only operators do.
2. AWS ec2 instances do not get reassigned the same public IP between the runs, so I have to run the `PythonOperator` to find out the public IP during every run.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`SSHOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.12/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/ssh_operator/index.html)'s `remote_host` parameter to set the host to which to connect. This setting "will replace the remote_host which was defined in ssh_hook or predefined in the connection of ssh_conn_id."

The `remote_host` parameter is templated, so you can read the IP from [XCOM using a template macro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46061162/6942134).

Comment: How do I do that? I'll have to use `XCom.get_one` method to get value, however, that method requires an `execution_date` parameter which is part of DAGRun, not DAG.

Comment: @abhinavkulkarni You can use {{ ti.xcom_pull(...) }}, as shown in the link that I provide. Without having a minimal reproducible example of your code it is rather hard to discuss details.

Comment: I ended up subclassing `SSHOperator` class wherein I have access to `context` in the `execute` function, in which I can pull XCom.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use elastic ip on ec2 so it doesn't change upon each start up.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).