# Airflow xcom_pull BashOperator return None

Tags: airflow

I'm trying to handle datetime output from the first BashOperator task but when I call the `process_datetime` task only the `dt` value returns None.
But when I schedule this Dag on airflow it works smoothly.

```py
def process_datetime(ti):
    dt = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='get_datetime') <--- get None
    if not dt:
        raise Exception('No datetime value.')

    dt = str(dt[0]).split()
    return dt

with DAG(
    dag_id='first_airflow_dag',
    schedule_interval='* * * * *',
    start_date=datetime(year=2022, month=2, day=1),
    catchup=False
) as dag:
    
    # 1. Get current datetime
    task_get_datetime = BashOperator(
        task_id='get_datetime',
        bash_command='date',
    )
    
    # 2. Process current datetime
    task_process_datetime = PythonOperator(
        task_id='process_datetime',
        python_callable=process_datetime
    )

task_get_datetime >> task_process_datetime
```

Answer (score 0):

> Templates like {{ ti.xcom_pull(...) }} can only be used inside of parameters that support templates or they won't be rendered prior to execution. See the template_fields, template_fields_renderers and template_ext attributes of the PythonOperator and BashOperator.

```
def process_datetime(**kwargs):
    ti = kwargs["ti"]
    dt = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='get_datetime')
    if not dt:
        raise Exception('No datetime value.')
    dt = str(dt[0]).split()
    return dt


with DAG(
     dag_id='first_airflow_dag',
     schedule_interval='* * * * *',
     start_date=datetime(year=2022, month=2, day=1),
     catchup=False
    ) as dag:

    # 1. Get current datetime
    task_get_datetime = BashOperator(
        task_id='get_datetime',
        bash_command='date',
    )

    # 2. Process current datetime
    task_process_datetime = PythonOperator(
        task_id='process_datetime',
        python_callable=process_datetime
    )
```

You can check it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46061162/14894585